# GHC Compile Errors

Tags: haskell, ghc

I created a very simple program:

```
module CompileTest(main) where

main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

When I try to compile it using `ghc CompileTest.hs` I get:

```
/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/libHSrtsmain.a(Main.o): In function `main':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `ZCMain_main_closure'
/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.1/libHSrtsmain.a(Main.o): In function `main':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `__stginit_ZCMain'
```

Does anyone know what this is? I'm not doing anything complicated. And it works fine in GHCi.

Comment: As an addition to Thomas' answer, with the `-main-is` flag, the `main` function need not be called `main`, you can use `ghc --make -main-is Foo.bar Foo.hs` to compile with the function `bar` in module `Foo` as entry point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` function must be in the `Main` module.  That or use the `-main-is` GHC flag.  Also, with GHC < 7 you need to use the compilation flag of `--make`.

Comment: GHC 7 doesn't require `--make` any longer?  I did not know that.